# I need help to implement a specific hibernate Inheritance mapping

Tags: java, spring, typescript, hibernate, mapping

I have a two classes, parent and child, and at child side I have a relation to itself. The database is modeled on two separate tables, both parent and child share the same "id", and the column "holder" is as foreign key for itself. I wrote the following code. I'm learning and I soon fall into this complex example of inheritance and interrelation and I would like to know if I used the notations correctly.

Person.class

> ```
> @Entity
> @Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
> @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
> @Table(name = "person")
> public class Person {
>
>   @Id
>   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
>   @Column(name = "id")
>   private Integer id;
>
>   @NotNull
>   @Column(name = "name")
>   private String name;
> }
> ```

Member.class

> ```
> @Entity
> @Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
> @Table(name = "member")
> public class Member extends Person {
>
>     @NotNull
>     @Column(name = "member_type")
>     private Integer memberType;
>
>     @Column(name = "id_holder")
>     private Integer idHolder;
>
>     @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Member.class)
>     @JoinColumn(name = "id_holder", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
>     private Member holder;
>
>     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "holder", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
>     private List<Member> dependents;
> }
> ```

And my object that will populate these entities on frontend is:

Member.model

> ```
> export class Member {
>     constructor(
>         public id?: number,
>         public name?: string,
>         public memberType?: number,
>         public idHolder?: any
>     ) {}
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answering my own question:

As I said, I'm still learning Spring Boot and Hibernate and I discovered that my  problem is a classic cyclic reference. I broke my cyclic reference setting my list of dependents (childs) as write-only, as I don't need this property for read every single time.

I also removed this idHolder redundant property.

Member.class

> ```
> @Entity
> @Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
> @Table(name = "member")
> public class Member extends Person {
>
>     @NotNull
>     @Column(name = "member_type")
>     private Integer memberType;
>
>     @ManyToOne
>     @JoinColumn(name = "id_holder", referencedColumnName = "id")
>     private Member holder;
>
>     @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
>     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "holder")
>     private List<Member> dependents;
> }
> ```

And now I know that I could manage this cyclic reference with JsonManagedReference/JsonBackReference too based on which entity I want to handle the relation and which one I want to leave it to the another. And other ways I still need to assimilate.